# How to disable only screen recording (not screenshot) in android and ios with Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, screenshot, screen-recording

I want to disable only screen recording in my flutter app. I used flutter_window_manager package but it disables both screen recording and screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any option in [flutter_window_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager) that would allow to distinguish between screen recording and screenshots. The underlying Android functionality also behaves the same, that is screenshot&recording aren't allowed see [Android FLAG_SECURE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE)

Just out of curiosity: How come you allow screen shots but not screen recording?